# Is there a way to prevent background application updating on both wi-fi and Mobile Data?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, mobile-data, application-autoupdate, background-process

For mobile there is an option to prevent it but I would like to block the updates and background data on Wifi also because I am connected to a Hotspot that uses Mobile Data from another mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can define that hotspot as being a "mobile hotspot", so Android would deal with it as if it were using mobile data:

1. Open *Settings*
2. Go to *Data Usage*
3. Tap the "overflow menu" (the 3 dots in the upper right)
4. From the menu opening, select *Mobile Hotspots*
5. Put a check-mark next to the hotspot you're using.

Comment: The mobile hotspot I am using does not appear in the list. However other mobile hots[pots I have used appear and have been automatically selected as "mobile hotspot". Did it ever happen to you that the mobiel hotspot does not appear in the list?

Comment: No. All hotspots I've used were always listed there. But I don't use the hotspot feature that often.